# Disable INFO logging messages in Ipython Notebook

Tags: python, ipython

I'm using requests_throttler and requests modules for communication through API. My script are writen in Ipython Notebook. I'm getting a lot of logging messages from requests_throttler module.
How may I disable or save to file log messages in Ipython Notebook? I got message like:

```
INFO:requests_throttler.throttler:Starting base throttler 'base-throttler'...
```

and want to send thousands of requests and this INFO messages will kill my notebook.

Answer (score 36):

If you just want to disable all INFO loggings in Jupyter Notebook just do the following inside your notebook:

```
#Supress default INFO logging

import logging
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.CRITICAL)
```

Comment: one-liner for lazyguys like me that like to save space in jupyter notebooks : `logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.CRITICAL)`

Answer (score 20):

For Python 3 you can simply do:

```
import logging, sys
logging.disable(sys.maxsize)
```

Comment: How to re-enable logging?

Comment: @AnmolDeep `logging.disable(logging.NOTSET)`?

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me under Python 2.7. (Other suggestions welcomed!)

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger('requests_throttler')
logger.addHandler(logging.NullHandler())
logger.propagate = False
```

Setting `logger.propagate` to `False` suppresses the lone remaining `"No handlers could be found for logger X.Y.Z"` message that you'd otherwise see.

To save to a file, check out [logging.FileHandler()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.handlers.html#filehandler).