# Suppress WARNING:matplotlib.legend:No handles with labels found to put in legend

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, legend

Sorry if this has been asked before but all the answers I found didn't work for me. I'm looking for a way to suppress this warning. The context is that I wrote a function that creates a lot of plots and sometimes I can't help but creating a legend for an unlabeled curve.

This is my sample code including what I tried

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore') # doesn't work

import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.CRITICAL) # doesn't work

plt.plot(np.random.rand(10))
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

The warning still appears like this

```
WARNING:matplotlib.legend:No handles with labels found to put in legend.
```

Comment: The `logging` option works well for me and I get the figure with no legend and no warning. Python 3.8, matplotlib 3.1.2. Also in python 2.7.

Comment: thanks I dug a bit deeper and found a solution in another stack overflow question

logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.CRITICAL)

Maybe it was related to using Jupyter Notebook

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution in this Stack Overflow Question.

[Disable INFO logging messages in Ipython Notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29651505/disable-info-logging-messages-in-ipython-notebook)

Maybe It was related to Jupyter Notebook?

```
import logging
logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.CRITICAL)
```