# Ignoring <IPython.core.display.HTML object> message

Tags: python, ipython, tsfresh

I'm using the package [tsfresh](https://tsfresh.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and keep getting the following message:

> <IPython.core.display.HTML object>

whenever I call the function extract_features with the following parameters:

```
extract_features(myDf,default_fc_parameters=MinimalFCParameters(),column_id="id", column_sort="time",disable_progressbar=True,n_jobs=6,show_warnings=False,profile=False)
```

How can I ignore this output?

I already tried the suggestions posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29651505/disable-info-logging-messages-in-ipython-notebook) but they don't work for me.

Comment: Are you calling extract_features from the interactive prompt? If so, then the HTML object may just be the return value of the function that the prompt prints if you do not assign the value to a variable. Try `_ = extract_features(...)`

Comment: No, I don't use the interactive prompt. I use PyDev instead.