# Stop Printing INFO:cmdstanpy:start chain 1, INFO:cmdstanpy:finish chain 1

Tags: python, facebook-prophet

I am running FBProphet with cmdstanpy instead of pystan. For my purpose, I have to run training and predictions multiple times in a jupyter notebook which results in constantly printing :

```
INFO:cmdstanpy:start chain 1
INFO:cmdstanpy:finish chain 1
```

The issue arises when I have to run this for more than 10000 models (Im predicting values for each day individually after updating the training set) and which prints 20000 lines. This makes the notebook extremely slow. Is there any way I can stop FBProphet frmo printing these two lines?

Things Ive tried:

1. Verbose False gives an error :

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-126-586e1241babb> in <module>
     17             model = Prophet(uncertainty_samples=True, weekly_seasonality = True, 
     18                             yearly_seasonality= True, changepoint_prior_scale = 0.5,
---> 19                             daily_seasonality=False, verbose = False)
     20             model.add_seasonality(name='monthly', period=30.5, fourier_order=2)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'verbose'
```

2. [how to control output from fbprophet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45551000/how-to-control-output-from-fbprophet)
   This does not supress the output.

Please Advice.

Answer (score 14):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34531590/5386903) works for me to turn off cmdstanpy info

mainly

```py
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger('cmdstanpy')
logger.addHandler(logging.NullHandler())
logger.propagate = False
logger.setLevel(logging.CRITICAL)
```

Comment: Thanks this works perfect, even using FBProphet

Answer (score 2):

The logging level can be controlled by the logger option in the CmdStanModel object when it is created:

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger('simple_example')
logger.setLevel(logging.WARNING)

CmdStanModel(stan_file=your_path,logger=logger)
```

See https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#logging-levels for more options. The above just creates a custom logger so that only warning-level messages will be printed, rather than the default info-level as defined in the CmdStanPy utils (https://cmdstanpy.readthedocs.io/en/v0.9.67/_modules/cmdstanpy/utils.html)

Comment: Where do you import `CmdStanModel` model from?

Answer (score 1):

This is how I solved the issue while I was working with PyCharm:

Go to `<your_virtual_env>\Lib\site-packages\cmdstanpy\utils.py`. Inside `get_logger()` method, update:

```py
handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
```

To this:

```py
handler.setLevel(logging.WARNING)
```

Comment: This is an option but will not work if you want your code to be run by others and have it function identically (since they will not have manually edited `utils.py` on their end)